# Unknown parse error from Haskell code for formating Text

Tags: haskell

I want to use Haskell to format Text with giving Strings and length of the line. But keep getting a same unknown error at "chunks" function for no reason!! Here is the code:

```
module Format where
data Format = Flushleft | Justify | Flushright

-- Help-function for chunks
oneChunk :: [String] -> [[String]]
oneChunk [] = [[]]
oneChunk (s:ls) = [words s] ++ oneChunk ls

chunks :: Int-> [String]-> [[String]]
chunks i s = chunk' i (oneChunk s) where
         chunk' i [[]] = [[]]
         chunk' i (fi:se:ls)
         | (length fi) + (length se) < i = [fi ++ se] 
                                            ++ chunk' i (se:ls)
         | otherwise = [fi] ++ [se] ++ chunk' i (se:ls)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Format.hs:13:14: error:
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
|
13 |              | (length fi) + (length se) < i = [fi ++ se] ++ 
chunk' i (se:ls)
|
```

Answer (score 4):

As it is stated in the error message the indentation is not correct. You need pattern guards to be indented relative to function declaration (see [Control structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures)).

So your code should be like this:

```
chunks :: Int-> [String]-> [[String]]
chunks i s = chunk' i (oneChunk s) where
    chunk' i [[]] = [[]]
    chunk' i (fi:se:ls)
         | (length fi) + (length se) < i = [fi ++ se] 
                                            ++ chunk' i (se:ls)
         | otherwise = [fi] ++ [se] ++ chunk' i (se:ls)
```

---

I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve but seems like you can simplify your code a bit.

`oneChunk` applies `words` to each element of its argument and adds `[]` to the end. This can be stated as (read a bit on [`map`s](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_II) and [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) for more info).

```
oneChunk = (++[]) . map words
```

`chunk'` uses variable `i` from `chunks` so you can just drop it. Also some parentheses are unneeded and you can replace `[x] ++ y` with `x:y`):

```
chunks :: Int-> [String]-> [[String]]
chunks i = chunk' . map words where
    chunk' [] = []
    chunk' (fi:se:ls)
         | length fi + length se < i = (fi ++ se) : chunk' (se:ls)
         | otherwise = fi : se : chunk' (se:ls)
```